# kubespray|ipvs|nginx|ingress : kube_proxy_mode: ipvs | nginx ingress crashlooping Address already in use

Tags: kubernetes

In a kubespray deployed cluster testing ipvs configuration with
the file config option in inventory/group_vars/k8s-cluster/k8s-cluster.yml has proxy mode set

```
kube_proxy_mode: ipvs
```

On the ipvs cluster kube-proxy is running on port 80 & 443

```
netstat -tunlp|grep proxy
tcp        0      0 10.144.104.83:80        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19455/kube-proxy
tcp        0      0 10.144.104.83:443       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19455/kube-proxy
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10249         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19455/kube-proxy
```

nginx ingress is crashlooping

```
bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

On a cluster deployed the same way except for proxy mode == iptables

```
netstat -tunlp|grep 443
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5367/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      5367/nginx: master

netstat -tunlp|grep proxy
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10249         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      28827/kube-proxy
```

Is there an option that I missed to alter kube-proxy acquiring ports 80 & 443 or is there an option needed to support running an ingress with ipvs I’ve overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Note: The nginx-ingress install is via a helm chart

Resolution:

ipvs mode with external ip opened a kube-proxy listener

Removing the array of externalIPs i.e. controller.service.externalIPs[0] turns off that mode